# Where does NSIS place .nsi file for created package

Tags: manifest, nsis, packaging

I created one package using NSIS but to install this package on any machine,it's asking for admin credentials. I tried to find out .nsi file for this created package to change `RequestExecutionLevel` but could not find that. Can anybody suggest where should I check for .nsi file that has been created for new package? 
As far as I know NSIS should generate .nsi file for package created. Correct me if I'm wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

NSIS itself does not create .nsi files, it expects you to write them yourself in your favorite editor. The only .nsi files provided by NSIS are in \NSIS\Examples.

A 3rd-party NSIS editor with a wizard feature might create a .nsi for you...